# How to parse continuously updated logs containing XML data?

Tags: text-processing, xml

Added the same question in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/QtZKcBic
(I see some xml tags are missing here when pasting)

I have a requirement to read from a continuously running logs which refreshes in milliseconds, because 1000's of people will be accessing in each and every minute.
My requirement is:

Suppose there is an xml request like this:

```
<dataReq>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>test</name>
  <reqId>ddaabyy234</reqid>
   ....
   ...
   ....
</dataReq>
```

And the response for the above request is:

```
<dataRes>
   <id>1</id>
   <dept>railway</dept>
   <reqId>ddaabyy234</reqid>
   .......
   .......
   <errcode>
       <errNum>404</errNum>
   </errcode>
 </dataRes>
```

If the `<errNum>` is not `200`, then I need to capture `<dataReq>..</dataReq>` and `<dataRes>..</dataRes>`

The problem here is, there can be multiple `<dataReq>...</dataReq>` tags. Because, in order to generate a response it will take some time for the backend systems and in the meanwhile many users will be sending their requests from webUI (or) mobile (or) apps to the same application.

The log will also be getting archived into archived files every 5 minutes as the log file  will be growing its size to huge withing every 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank You cas for formatting the content of the question.

Comment: to start with, don't parse the current log.  parse the archived logs...and keep track of the ones you've already processed (easiest way is to move the processed logs somewhere else after you've processed them).

Comment: formatting multi-line blocks of text as code is easy. Select the text you want to format, and press Ctrl-K.  For code fragments, commands etc embedded **in** a line, surround them with `\`` characters.

Comment: @cas, I agree. I think starting with archived log is good, as it will won't change and keeping track for it. Nice one...! Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe modify your app so that it doesn't generate such enormous and difficult to parse "log files" (they seem more like a complete data dump to me).   A single line summary of each request and the server's response (and maybe some other useful data) is more traditional - and usually more useful - for logs.

Comment: There are two types of logs. One is which we generate in the production environment. (prod environment will contain only single line as you mentioned).  Second one is QA, Staging and Dev boxes. These will contain the total request and response and this is expected. So, I will be working on QA, Staging and Dev environments.

Comment: a summary log is still useful.  you could add a unique id to each entry in both summary and dump logs, so that you can easily find/match the complete data in the dump log if/when you need it.   or put both summary and dump in the same log file (but still use a unique id to connect the two)

Comment: Capture ... and do what? That's the question. Capturing from a continuous log creates a continuous capture. Does that go into yet another log? Standard output in a console?

Answer (score 0):

The [TXR Language](https://nongnu.org.txr/) features "tail streams" in its library: these are stream objects that follow dynamic log files, similarly to the `tail -f` utility.

The function call `(open-tail "/path/to/it")` creates and returns a tail stream. The file need not exist yet. If and when the file does exist, the stream will read it until the end, and then monitor it for growth, sudden shrinkage, or disappearance/reappearance, giving the application the illusion of a flat, never ending stream of data. The application has to read from the stream fast enough, of course, relative to how often the file is rotated.

In the following program, we define a data structure to keep track of information about each transactions (request-response pairs) and use a tail stream to scan a log file called `data` using the TXR pattern language.

When we match a request, we create a new transaction object and put it into a hash table keyed on the ID.

When we see an failed response (code other than 200), we retrieve the transaction for the ID. If it exists, then we update it with the response information and print it (using the object's custom printing function that regenerates the XML request-response pair).

After matching a response, whether successful or not, we delete the matching transaction from the hash table.

```
@(do                                                                        
   (defstruct xact nil
     id
     req-inner-xml
     res-inner-xml
     (:method print (me *stdout* pretty-p)
       (cond
         (pretty-p
           (put-line "<dataReq>")
           [mapdo put-line me.req-inner-xml]
           (put-line "</dataReq>")
           (put-line "<dataRes>")
           [mapdo put-line me.res-inner-xml]
           (put-line "</dataRes>"))
         (t :))))

   (defvarl xact (hash)))
@(next (open-tail "data"))
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
<dataReq>
@    (all)
  <id>@id</id>
@    (and)
@      (collect)
@lines
@      (until)
</dataReq>
@      (end)
@    (end)
@    (do (set [xact id] (new xact
                             id id
                             req-inner-xml lines)))
@  (or)
<dataRes>
@    (all)
   <id>@id</id>
@    (and)
@      (skip)
   <errcode>
       <errNum>@err</errNum>
   </errcode>
@    (and)
@      (collect)
@lines
@      (until)
</dataRes>
@      (end)
@    (end)
@    (do
       (whenlet ((x (del [xact id])))
         (when (nequal err "200")
           (set x.res-inner-xml lines)
           (pprint x))))
@  (end)
@(end)
```